# What hero abilities can kill illusion heroes instantly (or close to instakilling)?

Tags: dota-2

My question is similar to [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/173922/63009), except that I'm looking for heroes with skills that can kill illusions easily without physical/AoE damage.

I played a game where opposite team had both Naga Siren and Chaos Knight. I don't really remember what I was playing or who my teammates were playing as, but I remember we got crushed badly. I know AoE heroes that do mass damage can take care of illusions decently (Sven), or a hero with massive Aoe spell damage would do too (CM, SK).

However, are there any heroes who can naturally kill illusions almost instantly? Also, do these skills make that hero worthy as a counter-draft, or is the better strategy just to stick with AoE damage?

Ones that I know of:

- **Medusa** - *Stone Gaze*, if petrified successfully, all petrified illusions die immediately
- **Disruptor** - *Glimpse*, will instakill a single illusion

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Abilities that can one shot illusions :

- [Hexes](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Hex) from Lion, Shadow Shaman (or Scythe of Vyse) : instakill
- [Mana Drain](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Mana_Drain#Mana_Drain) from Lion : illusion automatically dies after 0.25 sec
- [Life Drain](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Glimpse#Glimpse) from Pugna : illusion dies after the first tick of damage
- [Glimpse](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Glimpse#Glimpse) from Disruptor : instakill illusion
- [Stone Gaze](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Stone_gaze#Stone_Gaze) from Medusa : instakill any successfully petrified illusion
- [Purge](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Diffusal_Blade#Purge) from Diffusal Blade (not hero ability but could be usefull versus Morphling) : instakill

As far as I know those are the only that exists.

Comment: Also worthy to note is that Enchantress's skill Enchant can take over enemy illusions, Phantom Lancer illusions can create more illusions http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Enchantress#Abilities

Comment: True, I was hesitating to mention it aswell as chen's Holy persuasion aswell

Comment: I don't think that does anything to illusions? Enchant specifically states that it takes them over, Holy Persuasion does not, could be wrong.

Comment: Yes you're right, Chen's ability is limited to creeps

Comment: Just a curiosity about PL illusions: Wall of replica PL illusions can create illusions that can create illusions.

Comment: Would Medusa work well as a counter pick against illusion heroes, or is it a waste of time (I find that petrifying is easily avoided)? I guess the other heroes you listed would be situational.

Comment: @gitsitgo In pro game medusa is a very situational pick since she's easily countered and rely too much on farm to be efficient. In pub I can't say, I assume it's a valid strategie. According to [her dotabuff matchup page](http://dotabuff.com/heroes/medusa/matchups) she has a ~57.8% winrate (31k games) vs Naga and a 50% winrate (62k games) vs phantom lancer. Actually her 3 bests matchups are illusions based heroes so I'd say she's pretty legit

Comment: @WizLiz Shadow Demon has purge (ult) and the neutral satyr do have purge with low cooldown (Making Ench, Chen and Doom more valid)

Comment: @Wandang SD Purge does no damage to illusion, Satyre purge only deals 400 damage to illusion (on a low CD yes but single target anyway). Maybe 3 satyres can help a bit versus illusion in the early game but lategame they have no impact whatsoever

Comment: Legion Commander's Overwhelming Odds does increased damage to illusions/summons, so it's good against Naga and PL. But ofc, it doesn't kill them always, just does a lot of damage and it's an AOE ability. Earth Shaker's ult is also quite good against PL and Naga.

Answer (score -1):

Here are a few more. The list is kind of long actually but those came to mind.

Lion - manadrain

OD - first spell (can't remember the name) -> gives 4x dmg, pure dmg... that x(2 to 3) that the illusions have by default is kind of an instakill

Artefact - Defusal blade - purge

Also you can count here most of high damaging spells (like Linas or Lions ult) since most illusions can't handle them... but that's a waste of a good ult :).

Anyway... as a tip, when the other team has illusion heroes (like PL, CK, NS, etc.), just pick shaker. I just love when they are taking out illusions and I have shaker (with ult up of course).

The hardest illusion to kill in game I think is morphs ult, for that one I like to make a defusal.

Comment: Arcan orb only deals bonus damage to illusion, and the damage is pure, which can make you think it can instakill illusion. However with some tanky stats items, (Hearth of tarrasque and Skadi) your illusion can tank Arcane Orb without much trouble.

Comment: I said "kind of an instakill", and the question was about "kill illusions easily". Can you explain the -1? You added hexes and life drain from pugna, the rest being the same as mine and the question itself.

Comment: I didn't down vote this, but compared to the other answer this one has bad formatting and is difficult to understand.  Also the other answer has sources while this one does not.  Not sure if your answer was worthy of a down vote, but it could be much improved.

Comment: Generally, I agree with the others, but I gave you a +1 anyways for mentioning OD, still good to know info.